# How to open a PDF that is in the Drawable folder

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, itext

How to open a PDF that is in the Drawable folder using the Xam.iTextSharpLGPL v4.1.6 library.
I tried:

```
Uri _pathpdf = new Uri("android.resource://testpdf.testpdf/" + Resource.Drawable.Teste);
PdfReader _oldPdf = new PdfReader(_pathpdf);
```

Answers was to pass the PDF file to the Assets folder!

```
            PdfReader _oldPdf = new PdfReader(Assets.Open("Teste.pdf"));
```

Comment: The drawable-folder is not for files other then image-resources. You should use the asset-folder instead.

Comment: English please.

Comment: @tequila slammer with your help i found the answer!
`PdfReader _oldPdf = new PdfReader(Assets.Open("Teste.pdf"));`

Comment: iText 4.1.6 for .NET is not compatible with Android or Xamarin, it is also an obsolete version that is no longer supported.

Comment: I am using Xam.iTextSharpLGPL and so far everything is fine, created my pdf without conflicts

Comment: That's an unofficial version and not supported by iText Software.